# Custom Facebook authorize dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is a custom Facebook dialog? How to do similar? Are there an "official way" to do this?

See:
http://www.facebook.com/yazigi.oficial/app_352476968122012?ref=ts

I don't found nothing similar to this in the documentation and in the source code from example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the original Facebook Auth dialog, only used with parameter `display_mode=async`:

> *“async: For use only when loading a dialog via the JS SDK from within a Canvas or Page Tab App. Using async loads the dialog in a modal window. async is the default display mode within Canvas and Page Tab Apps.”*

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display